# How to parse links in bash output

Tags: linux, bash, terminal-emulator

Let assume that we have this output in bash console:

```
$ findgrep RAILS_ENV                                   
./script/munin_stats:7:RAILS_ENV = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || "development"
./script/munin_stats:12:    dbconfig = dbhash[RAILS_ENV]            
./lib/tasks/juggernaut.rake:4:    @rails_env = ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || "development"                             
./lib/tasks/cruise.rake:19:    ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'test'                                                     
./lib/tasks/populate.rake:15:      dumper = MysqlDumper.new(ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[RAILS_ENV])    
./lib/tasks/populate.rake:21:      dumper = MysqlDumper.new(ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[RAILS_ENV])    
./lib/tasks/populate.rake:29:      RAILS_ENV = "test"
```

How to create on file name (for example './script/munin_stats:7') clickable link (for example Ctrl+click) which will open selected file in my favourite editor?

Comment: Where have you seen "clickable links" in bash?

Comment: @Laurence: Most terminal emulators implement a similar feature with web links in console output..

Comment: same question on unix.se: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63417/

Answer (score 1):

This is more a function of the terminal emulator (e.g., xterm or gnome-terminal) than bash. The popular [urxvt](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/rxvt-unicode.html) terminal emulator (e.g. `apt-get install rxvt-unicode`) is extensible in Perl so  it should be possible to write a urxvt filter to take a selection and execute an editor based on the selection.

The default 'selection-popup' script (see [Perl source here](http://cvs.schmorp.de/rxvt-unicode/src/perl/selection-popup?view=markup)) already recognizes when you have a file:number pattern selected and offers the option to transform that into a vi command that will open the file at the right line.

Comment: Yea, it's not reall solution: 
1. must click
2. then click again on last in menu option
3. Switch back to vi
4. enter command mode in vi
5. paste with mouse middle button
6. Press enter

So it's 6 steps compated to 1 step required in original question. If you do this 100 times per days it makes big difference.

Answer (score 0):

[Hotwire](http://linuxappfinder.com/package/hotwire) can do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using GUI to display the list you can try zenity:

```
vi `findgrep RAILS_ENV * | cut -f 1 -d : |  zenity --list --column Files`
```

NB: it could be useful if you reveal the terminal emulator you (prefer to) use.